# Delete point if there are no other points in its surrounding

Tags: polygon, distance

I have three layers that cover the whole continent of Africa. Right now, they are in the geographic coordinate system WGS84 EPSG:4326. Layer "stations" shows the center of cells (of size 1/12 x 1/12 degrees), layer "grid" shows the respective cells, and layer "households" shows locations of households. Here is what I want to do:

I want to keep only those stations for which at least one household falls in its cell. I.e., I want to delete those green points for which no red point is in their cell.

How can I do this?

[image]

Comment: By now, I've managed to solve 1) by first creating a buffer around the points and then a grid with the extent of the buffer layer.

I now want to delete all polygons that have no orange points inside, and then only keep those green points that still have a polygon around.

Comment: We have a One question per Question policy, so you should probably [Edit] the Question to focus on the second issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an irregular point layer (blue) an a point grid (red), you can get those out of the red points that are 1) the centroids of a regular sqauare grid which 2) contain at least one of the blue points. Use QGIS expressions with [Geometry generator](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/training_manual/basic_map/symbology.html#hard-fa-geometry-generator-symbology) or [Geometry by expression](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#geometry-by-expression) (see here [for details](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/392619/88814)) with this expression on the points layer.

*Replace `Grid` (line 2) with the name of your grid layer and `100` (line 4) with the distance between red grid points.*

```
overlay_nearest(
    'Grid',  
    $geometry,
    max_distance:=sqrt(2)*100/2
)[0]
```

*Yellow points created by the expression, based on the `Grid` layer; black lines/squares just for visualization purpose:*
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! 

I tried to follow your suggestions, but I fail to solve the problem. I'm sorry, I'm very new to QGis.

This is what I did:
1. I opened "properties" of the point layer -> Symbology -> Geometry Generator -> Point / MultiPoint
2. I typed:

`overlay_nearest(  
    'Grid',  
    $geometry,  
    max_distance:=sqrt(2)*1/12/2  
)[0]`

where Grid is the grid layer and 1/12 the distance between the grid points (in degrees). What happens is that the point layer just disappears.

I don't know how to add a screenshot, so I'm not sure if you can follow.

Comment: You can edit your initial question to add a screenshot. Insert your expression in the layer styling, not in layer properties. Do not use geographic CRS (distance units in degrees), this does not work. Reproject your layer to a projected CRS, valid for your region of interest, e.g. local UTM zone. A screenshot could help, as well as sharing your data, at least a sample of it.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I adapted the original question so that it's clearer what I've done so far and what is still missing. When reprojecting it, which projected CRS should I take if the data is covering the whole African continent? The problem is, I also don't know the meter distance between the points.

Comment: For a proper CRS to cover the whole african continent **and** returning more or less correct distances, you should ask a separate question. It depends a lot on your final task, what you want to achieve and how accurate distances should be.

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved it for now is to use the tools "select by location" and "save selected features".

In a first step, I selected and kept only those grid cells that intersect with at least one household. In a second step, I then only selected and kept those stations that still lie within one of the remaining grids.

It took QGIS quite long to process it, but the result is as I wanted. It would be nice to have a Python code that does it in a quicker and more elegant way, but this approach seems to work as well.